# Properly Discontinuous Group Actions

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, group-actions, hyperbolic-geometry, discrete-geometry

Let $G$ be a group acting on a topological space $X$. We say the action of $G$ on $X$ is properly discontinuous (or $G$ acts properly discontinuously on $X$)
if one of the following two equivalent conditions is satisfied:

1. for every $x \in X$ and every compact subset $K$ of $X$ we have that the set $\{T \in G : T(x) \in K\}$ is finite.
2. for every compact subset $K$ of $X$ we have that the set $\{T \in G : T(K) \cap K \neq \phi \}$ is finite.

The question is how to prove the equivalence of these two conditions.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55726/properly-discontinuous-action

Comment: @IgorRivin Why would it answer? As far as I could see, the link discuss the condition 2. of the question  (which is named action of type B there) but I wasn't able to find any mention to the condition 1. of the present question there. Am I losing something?